# Return all items with Scala and MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka

I’m writing a CRUD in scala using akka-http and a MongoDB database.  I want to be able to return all items from a collection/table in MongoDB.

I have a router that looks like this:

```
  val imageRoute = {
pathPrefix("api") {
  pathPrefix("image") {
    get {
      path(Segment).as(FindByIdRequest) { request =>
        complete {
          repository
            .findById(request.id)
            .map { optionalImage => optionalImage.map {
              _.asResource
            }
            }
            .flatMap {
              case None => Future.successful(HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.NotFound))
              case Some(image) => Marshal(image).to[ResponseEntity].map { e => HttpResponse(entity = e) }
            }
        }
      }
    } ~ post {
      entity(as[ImageResource]) { image =>
        complete {
          repository
            .save(image.asDomain)
            .map { id =>
              HttpResponse(status = StatusCodes.Created, headers = List(Location(s"/api/images/$id")))
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  pathPrefix("images"){
    get{
      complete{
        repository
          .findAll()
      }
    }

  }
 }
}
}
```

And my repo looks like this:

```
class ImageRepository(collection: MongoCollection[Image])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {


  def findById(id: String): Future[Option[Image]] =
    collection
      .find(Document("_id" -> new ObjectId(id)))
      .head
      .map(Option(_))

  def findAll(): Observable[String] =
    collection
      .find()

  def save(image: Image): Future[String] =
    collection
      .insertOne(image)
      .head
      .map { _ => image._id.toHexString }
}
```

However when I run the findAll method, I just get an empty curly braces.  I’m not really sure what I’m doing wrong.

So, the solution was to change the findAll method so that it returned a Future[Seq], and implemented the toFuture method:

```
 def findAll(): Future[Seq[Image]] =
collection
  .find()
    .toFuture()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the driver doc: *In the API all methods returning a Observables are “cold” streams meaning that nothing happens until they are Subscribed to.*
Either subscribe to the Observable, or instead return a Future.

Doc: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.2/getting-started/quick-tour/

Comment: Hi there,I've changed the method so that it now returns a Future.  But now I get this error:Error:(22, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : org.mongodb.scala.Observable[Option[com.nk.crud.domain.Image]]
 required: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[com.nk.crud.domain.Image]]
      .map(Option(_))

Comment: Try .toFuture() on the .find()